# Is there a way to know which existing tab opened a new one in Firefox?

Tags: firefox, browser-tabs, tabs

I had an unwanted advertisement tab opened automatically recently in Firefox.

Assuming I am certain that it was opened by some other website I had already opened (not by a another program on my computer), is there a way to identify which tab has caused the opening of the new tab?

The goal is to analyze which was the origin to be able to flag / report it to my adblocker list, in addition to blocking the actual ad/malware tab site.

For instance, I was picturing examining some console/dev tool option or enabling some logging options (at least for the future occurrences). Maybe an extension that helps identify this.

(I am using Windows 10, just a standard Firefox MSI installation if that matters)

Comment: Do downvotes mean "it's not possible"?

Comment: An easy way to do this would be to open the tabs you had before, and then move them to their own windows by dragging them out of the window. Then after a while see which one has another tab. The only issue here is that this assumes you can reproduce it by opening the website again and also assuming that no other program caused it - this is very possible especially when Firefox is your default browser - a URL type will open in the default browser and this means another program may have caused it too. If you are certain it was the websites, open them in their own windows....

Comment: @QuickishFM That seems a valid answer, feel free to create one.

Comment: I have done so, thank you.

Comment: Why not simply install add-ons/extensions that prevent that kind of thing from happening? Stuff like uBlock Origin and NoScript (my favorites, but there are others who also do the job) would stop the unwanted ads and pop-ups, along with (potentially malicious) cross-scripting that's even more insidious because you don't see anything until it's too late. I understand that your question is more technical than that, and my answer to it would be "depends on how you've set up Firefox in the first place", but leaving your PC open to malware and ads, in this day and age, is simply beyond me.

Comment: @Didier Actually, I have indeed an adblocker, I can't imagine browsing the web without one. The main goal of my question was to be able to report the site / original advertising frames to my adblocker list's maintainers to prevent it slipping through, so, while your comment is useful advice, the point of my question remains.

Comment: @Didier  I also agree on NoScript being a better shield than simple adblockers, I use it, however I also share a computer with non-tech-savvy persons and NoScript is a bit harsh for those persons. That's on this one that the culprit tab appeared. I'll gladly test uBlock origin, thanks for pointing that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An easy way to do this would be to open the tabs you had before, and then move them to their own windows by dragging them out of the window. Then after a while see which one has another tab.

The only issue here is that this assumes you can reproduce it by opening the website again and also assuming that no other program caused it - this is very possible especially when Firefox is your default browser - a URL type will open in the default browser and this means another program may have caused it too. If you are certain it was any of the open tabs, open them in their own windows and see which one gets a new tab.